# How do I set a variable equal to the value of an attribute within a child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to set a variable equal to the value of the name of a form in the following html.

```
<div id="someid">
    <form name="somename">
    </form>
</div>
```

Here I have tried to set var x equal to the name of the form but I don't think I'm going about this correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#someid").length > 0){
         var x = $($("#someid").children("form")).attr("name");
        if(x !== undefined){
            alert(pkmnId);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: _"but I don't think I'm going about this correctly"_ what makes you think that? Is your `alert(pkmnId)` line not getting triggered? Also you wouldn't be able to use `x` outside your ready callback since it is a local variable (if that is what you are attempting)

Comment: what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: My alert is not getting triggered but I have since set up a mock webpage with equivalent html and it is working there so I think I have misidentified the problem. Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only problem with this line

```
var x = $($("#someid").children("form")).attr("name");
```

is that you are passing a jquery object to the jquery method where either a DOM element is expected or a selector is expected.

change is to

```
var x = $("#someid").children("form").attr("name"); //observe removing extra $ from the beginning.
```

Comment: jQuery allows passing in another jQuery object, it's just not necessary as it's just going to return a new jQuery object representing the same collection. Both lines amount to the same thing

Comment: @PatrickEvans please check jquery doc here http://api.jquery.com/jquery/, none of the constructors is taking jquery object as parameter.

Comment: Actually one does, its the fifth link: [jQuery( selection )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selection). Also if you are adventrous you can look at their code: inside [jQuery.fn.init](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L20), a jQuery object would fail all if statements and the function would then just return `jQuery.makeArray(selector,this)` you could then go down all the calls and see what it ultimately returns is a cloned jQuery object.

Comment: @patrickevans 5th one is mentioned as a plain object, not the jQuery object. Don't know what that plain object is though.

Comment: 6th one, its below the plain object one, _"jQuery( selection ) selection Type: jQuery An existing jQuery object to clone."_

Answer (score 1):

Take more advantage of your selectors

```
$("#someid form").attr("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, only by using javascript

```
<div id="someid">
    <form name="somename">
    </form>
</div>


<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("someid").children;
    console.log(x[0].name);

</script>
```

you will be getting **somename** in the console, store it in a variable

```
var _y = x[0].name;
```

Comment: This will not work if the div contains any elements other than the form (which seems to be likely).

Comment: `value of the name of a form in the following html.` this is the question. He is talking about this particular problem. BTW you are correct.

Comment: True, but given `someid` and `somename`, I assumed it was a trivialized example.